# Unusual redirect is tripping up Boost

Tags: redirection, caching

My employer maintains a Drupal site we did not develop so we don't fully understand it. Recently I installed Boost on the dev site, it improved page load speed tremendously, but when I installed it in Production, after a day or so links to the home page were being diverted to another page, the URL of an older site that is now superseded by a subpage within the new site. It seems that this redirect may be legacy code that is no longer necessary. In any case I located the code that generates this redirect in the html.tpl.php file. It is completely custom as the default html.tpl.php has nothing resembling it. I'm going to test removing it, but was hoping somebody might be able to offer a more knowledgeable explanation of what it is doing.  Here's the code:

```
global $base_url;
$href = $base_url;
$path = drupal_get_path_alias($_GET['q']);
if ($path[0] == 'awards' OR strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'], 'awards') !== false) {
$head_title = $title . ' | Alternatesite.info';
$href = "http://www.alternate_site.info/";
$is_alternate_site = true;
}
else {
$href = $base_url;
$is_alternate_site = false;
}
```

There is probably a way to cancel this redirect either in htaccess or Boost, which are probably beyond my pay grade. I will try removing the code first.

Thanks to anyone who can shed light on this.